# Decoupling WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, oop, decoupling

I understand this is a high level question (maybe even vague), but without going into detail, here it is...

We are designing a wcf service to act as a translator between two large internal web apps.   Each app has it's own domain classes.  Our service will be called by both, passing in domains and returning responses from the other app.  Team members do not want to share projects between solutions because of source control issues.  What would be the best/proper way of handling domain objects in both solutions, without referencing the other applications?   The current consensus is to maintain the domain classes in both the major apps and the translator.

Answer (score 0):

You should not maintain domain classes in your "translator" service.

Ideally you should use the "translator" service's datacontract to pass objects in and out of it. Your "translator" service should have a data contract project, which is referenced by both web apps. Domain classes must not be referenced anywhere but within their own domain.